# how to check whether der is a uniform thing in front of the camera.?

Tags: android, camera

i want to make an app ...in which i have to check whether der is a brown stick in front of the camera(when it is on ofc )..and measure its size on the screen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mate not to be a troll or something but that in all seriousness is hard like hell! You would basically have to have a whole image analysis algorithm written up to look for specific patterns in the colors of the pixels on your camera.

You have to understand that a computer (phone in this case) cannot recognize objects within images like we humans do.

You would have to write up the application to recognize what the color brown is (which means from what hex color code to what hex color code you want to define as brown). Then you would have to teach it the pattern of the stick which is in what positions on the screen the brown pixels should be.

I don't know i for one think that is way too complicated for just one person to do. But prove me wrong if you can i will gladly eat my words.